# Making own queries Google Analytics (Java)

Tags: java, maven, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement the google analytics library in a website in order to make my own queries and obtain some kind of data to manage them afterwards.

I have followed the example and everything works fine. However, I am only able to code the example query (visitors in last week). I've read many information and documentation about that and I'm still having the same issue.

I'm sure there must be a way to accomplish that, but actually I'm not able to code anything to make my own queries.

The code is (I'm using maven):

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Accounts;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Profiles;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperties;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API using a service
 * account.
 */
public class test {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "example";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = //route to p.12 file;
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = //mail example;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();

            String profile = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
            System.out.println("First Profile Id: " + profile);
            printResults(getResults(analytics, profile));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
        // Initializes an authorized analytics service object.

        // Construct a GoogleCredential object with the service account email
        // and p12 file downloaded from the developer console.
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(AnalyticsScopes.all())
                .build();

        // Construct the Analytics service object.
        return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
        // Get the first view (profile) ID for the authorized user.
        String profileId = null;

        // Query for the list of all accounts associated with the service account.
        Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

        if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No accounts found");
        } else {
            String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();

            // Query for the list of properties associated with the first account.
            Webproperties properties = analytics.management().webproperties()
                    .list(firstAccountId).execute();

            if (properties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
            } else {
                String firstWebpropertyId = properties.getItems().get(0).getId();

                // Query for the list views (profiles) associated with the property.
                Profiles profiles = analytics.management().profiles()
                        .list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId).execute();

                if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println("No views (profiles) found");
                } else {
                    // Return the first (view) profile associated with the property.
                    profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
                }
            }
        }
        return profileId;
    }

    private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
        // Query the Core Reporting API for the number of sessions
        // in the past seven days.
        return analytics.data().ga()
                .get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions")
                .execute();
    }

    private static void printResults(GaData results) {
        // Parse the response from the Core Reporting API for
        // the profile name and number of sessions.
        if (results != null && !results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("View (Profile) Name: "
                    + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());
            System.out.println("Total Sessions: " + results.getRows().get(0).get(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No results found");
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the code that makes the queries is:

```
private static GaData getResults(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    // Query the Core Reporting API for the number of sessions
    // in the past seven days.
    return analytics.data().ga()
            .get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions")
            .execute();
}
```

The problem is: how I set dimensions of my queries using this code?

This query works (without dimensions):

```
 private static GaData getMobileTraffic(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
        return analytics.data().ga()
                .get("ga:" + profileId, "30daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions, ga:pageviews, ga:sessionDuration")
                .execute();
    }
```

This one doesn't work (with dimensions):

```
 private static GaData getMobileTraffic(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
        return analytics.data().ga()
                .get("ga:" + profileId, "30daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions, ga:pageviews, ga:sessionDuration",**"ga:userType"**)
                .execute();
    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second code example does not do the query, it returns the id for the first data view in the first account authorised by your credentials..  The actual query is in the getResults method, specificially   the analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, "7daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions").execute(); (return from view id data starting seven days ago until today with the number of sessions as metric). That is the line you need to change.

Comment: You are right @EikePierstorff. I've edited my answer. Unfortunately the issue still there

Comment: There is a complete example in the docs, doesn't that help (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) ? The dimensions and metrics reference show which values you can query (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).  Metrics (numbers) are added to the query as fourth parameter in the get method (ga:sessions in your example, use a comma separated list for multiple metrics), and you can chain the setDimensions-methods to it for categorical data (i.e. .setDimensions("ga:source,ga:keyword").

Comment: I have also tried this. In this case I have a problem when I call GET apiQuery... I don't know where to insert that piece of code but I tried everything

Comment: Can you post the code for your non-working query so there is something to debug ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Sorry for the delay. I've finally performed a new query (that is edited in the post) but I cannot set dimensions on it... The problem still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that I've finally solved my issue. I answer myself in order to help someone with similar problems and hope it works for them too.

The answer is simply, the documentation about Google Analytics is a bit confusing, but if someone wants to add dimensions, metrics (or edit the example query from Google analytics) just need to add the code in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide

Just adding this code just following the query example (if you want to add dimensions):

```
setDimensions("ga:userType")
```

So, the final code will be:

```
  private static GaData getMobileTraffic(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
        return analytics.data().ga()
                .get("ga:" + profileId, "30daysAgo", "today", "ga:sessions, ga:pageviews, ga:sessionDuration").setDimensions("ga:userType")
                .execute();
    }
```

Note that in the main code, you need to add the print function, just like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
        printMobileTraffic(getMobileTraffic(analytics, profile));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```